Hardhat: "The contract 0x...has already been verified", but is not my contract code
I changed contract name of pancakeswap v3 factory contract like this.
PancakeV3Facory -> MyV3Factory
I deployed it successfully and tried it to verify using hardhat verify plugin.
But it says "The contract 0x...has already been verified".
When I checked on bscscan, I noticed that it is verified with pancakeswap factory code.
How to fix this?
Can I reverify with MyV3Factory code?

hi there, can you please provide detailed logs as well
